# Changing style of marker with loading geoJSON

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

So i want to make simple html webpage with my analytical data on it.
I gather all of my data inside of valid geoJSON.
I used this for HTML part:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>GeoJSON + Flask + MongoDB</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>
    Let's display some nice maps here!
</h1>
<div id="map" style="height: 80vh;"></div>

<script>

const map = L.map('map').setView([55.73135, 37.59104], 10);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: 'Open street map',
}).addTo(map);


axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/points')
  .then((response) => {
    L.geoJSON(response.data, {
      style(feature) {
        console.log(feature);
        if (feature.properties.count < 5) {
          return { color: '#3cb043' };
        }
        if (feature.properties.count < 8) {
          return { color: '#fad201' };
        }
        return { color: '#ff0033' };
      },
    }).addTo(map);
  });


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It shows markers on the map but doesn't really color them.
I tried to make it green for points where count less than 5, yellow for less than 8 and red for the other cases.
I feel like problem is about `axios.get` but i'm not much of a front-end guy so I don't really know what's wrong.
Also I added `console.log(feature)` just to see if the function is ever called and it doesn't seem like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i figured out that calling style didn't work and changed it to `pointToLayer`
Here's correct markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>GeoJSON + Flask + MongoDB</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>
    Let's display some nice maps here!
</h1>
<div id="map" style="height: 80vh;"></div>

<script>

const map = L.map('map').setView([55.73135, 37.59104], 10);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: 'Open street map',
}).addTo(map);

var greenMarkerOptions = {
    radius: 8,
    fillColor: "#3cb043",
    color: "#000",
    weight: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    fillOpacity: 0.8
};

var yellowMarkerOptions = {
    radius: 8,
    fillColor: "#fad201",
    color: "#000",
    weight: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    fillOpacity: 0.8
};

var redMarkerOptions = {
    radius: 8,
    fillColor: "#ff0033",
    color: "#000",
    weight: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    fillOpacity: 0.8
};


axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/points')
  .then((response) => {
    L.geoJSON(response.data, {
      pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        if (feature.properties.count < 3) {
          return L.circleMarker(latlng, greenMarkerOptions);
        }
        else if (feature.properties.count < 6) {
          return L.circleMarker(latlng, yellowMarkerOptions);
        }
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, redMarkerOptions);
      },
    }).addTo(map);
  });


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Markers can't be colorized with the default leaflet library, you can only change the icon:
https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/

You can try a library like this: https://github.com/lvoogdt/Leaflet.awesome-markers

Comment: Thank you I didn't notice that tutorial on coloring was about polygons, not markers:(